# Лучше подключать несколько файлов малым весом, или один - но большой?

Tags: javascript, css, http, минификация

Есть у меня например 5файлов стилей, весом каждый пусть будет 150кб (пример).
Если их склеить и минифицировать - получится 750кб.

Так вот думаю, как лучше их на страницу подключать, одним файлом, или лучше 5 файлов отдельно?

Если используется HTTP 1.1.

Comment: Склеивать рекомендуют и css, и js.

Comment: Если у вас этот процесс склейки автоматизированный, то можно склеить. Там где я программирую практикуется подход все сторонние библиотеки в один файл склеиваются, а свои файлы во второй. Но особой разницы в производительности думаю вы не заметите.

Comment: Нужно брать и измерять для вашего конкретного случая и для вашего среднестатистического посетителя, а не спрашивать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут в целом всё довольно однозначно. В абсолютных величинах грузить один файл быстрее, так как убирается куча накладных расходов на организацию подключений, если файлов несколько.

Вот только не всё так гладко.

1. Если вы уверены, что файл стилей не будет почти меняться, то да, однозначно лучше склеивать.
2. Вопрос кеширования. Если всё склеить, то при смене хоть какой-то части клиенту придётся перекачивать один жирный файл. Так что, относительно статичные стили лучше склеить, а те, что часто меняются отдельно грузить. Некий баланс.